# using 'window' in useEffect dependency - NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a function which should run when `window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type` changes. I am trying to do this with useEffect, but I get the window is not defined reference error.How should I run the function on the change?
Edit:
The basic idea is that, that a player can create a room, and with the room id an another can join. But if the host leaves the page the room should be closed, or if the other player leaves the room the player should leave the room.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    interrupt()
  }, [window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type]);

async function interrupt(){

    if (players && currentRoom && window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type == 'reload') {
        const docRef = doc(db, "versus_ongoing", currentRoom)

        if(players.players[0].user == user.uid){
            deleteDoc(docRef)
        } else {
            await updateDoc(docRef, {
                players: players.players.filter(post => post.host == true)
            })
        }
      } else {
        console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
      }   
}
```

Comment: Are you using SSR? You can check if `window` is undefined in a guard clause before proceeding with accessing any properties of `window`, e.g. `if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;`

Answer (score 0):

I think that window is not available in NextJS until the mount is completed and since it references window in the deps array itself, its actually being consumed before that.

Using this in the deps array won't work anyway sadly, since effect dependencies can only be state or props -- or it won't trigger when it changes.

I don't know enough about your use case but I don't think `window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type` ever changes anyway? In which case, you simply don't need it in the deps array:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    interrupt()
  }, []);
```

Comment: Hey! `window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type` does change. How should I run the function on its change?

Comment: Unless the web api provides events that fire when this change, or you know beforehand that it changes after a certain user action you can hook into -- your only option woud be polling. When does it change, when you navigate pages?

Comment: The window performance object isnt really supposed to be used for actual business logic like this, so I suspect it may be a case of wrong tool for the job -- but id have to know more about the use case.

Comment: I would like to delete a document in firestore on page reload.

Comment: Specifically on reload only and not when user navigates back/forward? Im interested to know about why you want to distinguish if so (is curious to me -- the desire to do it kind of signifies a possible deeper design flaw). Does your site use HTML5 push state or is it server based routing? If the former, I have some ideas.

Comment: So the basic idea is that, that a player can create a room, and with the room id an another can join. But if the host leaves the page the room should be closed, or if the other player leaves the room the player should leave the room. Do you have a better way doing what I want to achieve?

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, I think there are better ways, but fundamentally you will need your own server to achieve it as you need some code running elsewhere that is managing the games. With this solution, the server would give a grace period when no connection has been seen from the user (probably using websockets) for n amount of time. Its the only reliable way to do this really, you cant rely on the client.

Comment: You could probably do it purely clientside i guess by putting a token in the HTML5 history state and then you would know it was a reload because it would be gone when they refresh. You can detect page leave events easily enough with HTML5 push state api. Such solutions that rely on the client letting the server know though are probably a vector that can be exploited. What if the user kills the browser task? You really need open sockets to a server you manage and then monitor those sockets serverside.

Comment: You could still have the client let the server know (via history events) though you cant 100% rely on this happening. When it does let the server know though, likely the server should not delete the player immediately, but give a small grace period. If the user returns within n seconds, cancel the pending deletion. This background async task would be a server side thing. If they dont return, have the server go ahead with the delete.